# React Hooks, API, Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

**I have a problem in my axios api calls, i'm using 2 apis in the same function, both of axios calls works good alone but when i combine them i got error in the Country components which i will be posting after, the error is ( map is not a function )**

```
const onSerializeData = () => { 
    const serializedCountries = serializeCountries(selectedCountries, false);
    //Print the Countries
    console.log(
      `Selected Countries: \n ${JSON.stringify(serializedCountries)}`
    );
    
    axios
      .get(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${
          serializedCountries[serializedCountries.length - 1]
        }`
      )
      .then((responose) => {
        const CouAllData = responose.data;
        console.log("CouAllData", CouAllData);
        setCountryAllData([...CountryAllData, CouAllData]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
      axios
      .get(
        `https://corona-api.com/countries/${
          serializedCountries[serializedCountries.length - 1]
        }`
      )
      .then((responose) => {
        const CouData = responose.data.data; //The Data
        setCountryData([...CountryData, CouData]); //set The Data to the OBJ
        console.log(" setCountryData", CountryData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  };
return (
<div>
<Country countries={CountryData} /> 
      <Country countriesAll={CountryAllData} /></div>
}
```

**Country Component**

```
const DataGroup = this.props.countries.map((county) => {
      return <Data info={county} />;
    });

    const DataGroupAll = this.props.countriesAll.map((country) => {
      return <Data infos={country} />;
    });

    return (
      <div>
         {DataGroup}
         {DataGroupAll}
      </div>
```

**Data Component**

```
 <h1>Name : {this.props.info.code}</h1>
        <h1>Date : {this.props.info.updated_at}</h1>
<h1>Name : {this.props.infos.name}</h1>
        <h1>Capital : {this.props.infos.capital}</h1>
```

Comment: Often, when you get `.map()` is not a function error, it means whatever you're trying to map is not an array. So is `this.props.countries` an array?

Comment: Yes it is actually an array, i initialize it as an empty array then pass to it the informations

Comment: You need to provide fuller context of what you're trying to do. It's hard to troubleshoot based on snippets of code. For example how are you calling your `onSerializeData` function? I don't see any references to it other than its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `axios.all()` to perform concurrent requests.

```
function getCountries() {
  return axios.get(
    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${
      serializedCountries[serializedCountries.length - 1]
    }`
  )
}

function getCountries2() {
  return axios.get(
    `https://corona-api.com/countries/${
      serializedCountries[serializedCountries.length - 1]
    }`
  )
}

Promise.all([getCountries(), getCountries2()])
  .then(function (results) {
    const countries = results[0];
    const countries2 = results[1];
  });
```

Comment: and where exactly should i put the setSteat>>  const CouAllData = responose.data;
      
        setCountryAllData([...CountryAllData, CouAllData]);

Comment: Inside the promise returned by `.then()`

Comment: I tried the code you gave me, but it gives me the same error